# Alternate between writing to text file and console in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to write to a text file. Then, I want to continue printing to the console.

I am able to successfully output to the text file. However, after closing the PrintStream created to write to the text file, I am unable to print to the console. In the code below, for instance, the text file has the output from the method called "permutation" followed by the phrase "Test before close". However, the phrase "Test after close" is printed to neither the text file nor the console. Thanks for any advice!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(out2);
    permutation("1234");
    System.out.println("Test before close");
    out2.close();
    System.out.println("Test after close");
}
```

Comment: java and javascript are different languages.

Comment: I am that much of a newbie; I did not know. Thanks :o)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use system.setOut to write to a file, what you are doing is overriding "System.out" and not resetting it.  If you really want to do it you should add:

saveOut=System.out

before the setOut, and then before the last line add:

System.setOut(saveOut)

to put the original system.out back.

Redirect the streams all you want, just don't cross them.

Answer (score 0):

Store `System.out` (by default, the console) in a variable somewhere before you `setOut`.

```
oldOut = System.out;
```

Then, after (or before) `out2.close();`, add:

```
System.setOut(oldOut);
```

This restores the old standard output, allowing you to print to the console again.

(What your code was actually doing is leaving `System.out` set to `out2`, which is now closed; so all your output will go into a black hole.)